# Does the Chokehold feat only apply the penalty when you first establish the pin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, grapple

I'm looking into building a monk and I couldn't help but notice the feat [Chokehold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/chokehold-combat). It's fairly neat and allows you to suffocate an opponent you hold in a chokehold.

Does the initial −5 penalty only apply when you first establish the pin, and not to subsequent checks for an opponent attempting to break free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

According to the [Chokehold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/chokehold-combat) Combat Feat:

> While you have an opponent up to one size category larger than you **grappled**, you can attempt a grapple combat maneuver with a –5 penalty on the check. If you succeed, you have **pinned** your opponent and hold the opponent in a chokehold.

The [Pinned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned) status states:

> Pinned is a more severe version of grappled, and their effects do not stack.

As the effect of success is a change of status from Grappled to Pinned, you would not be applying the penalty to subsequent grapple check to maintain the status.